# pipe unlimited curl stdout into chunked files

Tags: streaming, curl, pipe

I've got an HTTP-endpoint that serves an unlimited stream of events.
Now I'd like to record that stream using curl, but splitting the recorded files at the same time - preferably based on the line number to prevent corruption.

I've tried split, but it seems that split does nothing until the input stream is over.

This is my command:

```
stdbuf -oL curl -s http://... | split -l1 - record.chunked.
```

For testing: The following command tries to split the result of the ping command into files with 1 line each. But it does not work.

```
ping localhost | split -l1 - out.
```

Is there another (lean, easy, preferably without scripting) way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you wanted to avoid scripting for this, but I have made a really simple solution.  Take a look:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#
# read infinitely from /dev/stdin and print into files for every 100 lines
# Written by Guy Gastineau. 3/20/2019 - Free to use!
#

# create unique names for the logs
set_filename () {
  filename="${HOME}/eventlogs/$(date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S').log"
}

# error if eventlogs dir doesn't exist
if [[ ! -d ${HOME}/eventlogs ]]; then
  printf '%s\n' "~/eventlogs doesn't exist. Please create this directory" >&2
  exit 1
fi

# initialize vars
idx=0; set_filename

# read from stdin
while read -r line; do
  printf '%s\n' "$line" >> $filename # print to file
  $(( idx++ )) 2> /dev/null          # increment idx, and ignore output
  if [[ $idx -ge 100 ]]; then        # reset vars when idx gets to 100
    idx=0; set_filename
  fi
done
```

Feel free to change the base path for the file name if you want the logs somewhere else.  Also changing the integer in the test on line 25 will change the number of lines put in each file before creating a new file.

IMPORTANT! this script will run as long as it can read from stdin.

PS. I tested this with `ping google.com | myscript` and it worked like a charm.